# Generating sequential alphanumeric numbers

Tags: python

Need better ways to generate ascendingingly sequential strings that start from AAAAA00001 through ZZZZZ99999?

E.g.
AAAAA00001,
AAAAA00002,
…….
AAAAA99999,
AAAAB00001,
….
ZZZZZ99999

The current sample that is under use is highly unoptimised (I feel) as follows:

```
def generateAlphanumericSequence():
    for i in range(65, 91):
        for j in range(65, 91):
            for k in range(65, 91):
                for l in range(65, 91):
                    for m in range(65, 91):
                        for z in range(1, 100000):
                            print '%s%s%s%s%s%05d' % (chr(i), chr(j), chr(k), chr(l), chr(m), z)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: better == optimized in terms of memory, readability, extensibility, etc etc

Comment: @Tichodroma -- This isn't base 36 encoding though because `AAAAA0000A` is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.product`.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import itertools
def generateAlphanumericSequence():
    for i,j,k,l,m in itertools.product(ascii_uppercase,repeat=5):
         for z in range(1, 100000):
              yield '%s%s%s%s%s%05d' % (i, j, k, l, m, z)
```

You could easily generalize this to accept any number of characters in the front (if you use `str.join` to fix the output of `itertools.product`):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import itertools
def generateAlphanumericSequence(repeat=5):
    for seq in itertools.product(ascii_uppercase,repeat=repeat):
         sseq = ''.join(seq)
         for z in range(1, 100000):
              yield '%s%05d' % (sseq, z)
```

And of course, you could use default arguments for the range too -- You'd just need to figure out how many digits you need to create your `%0?d` string, but you could get that with `math.log10`.  e.g.

```
fmtstring = '%s%0{size}d'.format(size=int(math.log10(rmax-1)+1))
```

*see comments by myself and @DSM for other options regarding the numeric portion -- There might be an optimization opportunity there too.  You'd need to `timeit` and see.*

Comment: @iMom0 -- Turns out that I am too :)

Comment: Instead of the inner range, you could use `product(string.digits, repeat=repeat)` and get rid of the `%05d`.

Comment: @DSM -- That's true, but I wouldn't consider that easier to read -- I'm not sure about efficiency here either.  It would require a `join` in the innermost loop which I would imagine could get costly.

Comment: @DSM -- Could also use `str(z).zfill(5)`.  Not sure how that would compare either though.

Comment: The `%` string formatting operator supports field widths (the `*` character); see my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I suppose that makes sense.  If I remember correctly, `C` does too, so why not python?  I still think that I would prefer building the format string ahead of time -- then the underlying implementation doesn't have to resolve the `*` at each step.  It's probably a micro optimization, but it's in the inner loop, and this thing is generating *A lot* of numbers (as you've pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

You are basically counting from 0 to 1188137599999 ((26 ** 5) * 100000 - 1), but with the value over 100000 expressed in base 26 with only letters. If you separate the number formatting from the counting, you get:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

def _format(value, lettercount=5, digitcount=5):
    upper, lower = divmod(value, 10 ** digitcount)
    letters = []
    for i in xrange(lettercount):
        upper, val = divmod(upper, 26)
        letters.insert(0, ascii_uppercase[val])
    return '%s%0*i' % (''.join(letters), digitcount, lower)

def lettercounter(lettercount=5, digitcount=5):
   for i in xrange((26 ** lettercount) * (10 ** digitcount)):
       yield _format(i, lettercount, digitcount)
```

and it'll efficiently generate all your values one by one.

Demo:

```
>>> lettercounter().next()
'AAAAA00000'
>>> _format(123456789)
'AABVM56789'
>>> _format(26**5*100000-1)
'ZZZZZ99999'
```

The functions also accept arbitrary number and letter lengths:

```
>>> lettercounter(2, 2).next()
'AA00'
```

My method has the advantage you can format arbitrary numbers to a letters + digits sequence numbers, as well as generate the sequence starting at 0. [mgilson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087132/100297) is probably faster though, as using `itertools.product` to generate the letter sequence doesn't require you to decompose the upper half of the sequence number into a set of base 26 'digits'.