# Generate alphanumeric string in python

Tags: python, django

I am following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13087302/4652234) because I need to generate a sequential string one by one. I am using it in a django form so I need it to increment. However, I cannot get it to work.. All I am getting is AAAA00000 every refresh I made.

This is the code:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

def _format(value, lettercount=5, digitcount=5):
    upper, lower = divmod(value, 10 ** digitcount)
    letters = []
    for i in range(lettercount):
        upper, val = divmod(upper, 26)
        letters.insert(0, ascii_uppercase[val])
    return '%s%0*i' % (''.join(letters), digitcount, lower)

def lettercounter(lettercount=5, digitcount=5):
    for i in range((26 ** lettercount) * (10 ** digitcount)):
        yield  _format(i, lettercount, digitcount)
```

Then in my views:

```
#this is when the page loads.
addcodegenerate = codegenerate(initial={'id_gen': lettercounter()})
```

and the value that's appearing in my text field is:

```
<generator object lettercounter at 0x038E4AA8>
```

The 0x0... part changes every time I load the page so I assume that I am getting a different value, BUT this is what I get as an output.

I also tried it in a separate .py file and I also don't get any output.

It's supposed to increment every time I load the page.. Like AAAAA00000, AAAAA00001 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening with the `0x0` part changing is that when `codegenerate` (I don't know what that is exactly or how it is actually called in the context of your code) gets called each time, a new/fresh instance of the `lettercounter` generator is returned.  You can specifically create a fresh instance of the generator by doing this in the module that defined it:

```
lettercounter_inst = lettercounter()
```

Then you need to actually get the `next` string value from your generator function rather than letting your code (inside `codegenerate`) casting that object into a string (this is what causes the raw repr expression of the generator to appear in your text field).  Like so:

```
addcodegenerate = codegenerate(initial={'id_gen': next(lettercounter_inst)})
```

However, in the context of django I assume you want to persist the results  submitted by the users and it's best to rely on the database or construct a model associated with it, and then have a function that cast the associated auto-increment value to the alphanumeric string you desire.

Comment: I am still getting the same result..`<generator object lettercounter at 0x037B1030>`

Comment: Oh yeah. Missed next() function.. But now the problem is nothing is displaying in the text field anymore.. I can see that the value increments already by printing it, but the value is not displayed in the text field.

Comment: If the correct value can be printed but not displayed in your text field some other unrelated logic must be doing this.  What is `codegenerate` doing with the `initial` argument?

Comment: `codegenerate` is my form and `initial` is to initialize a value when the form is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new generator each time the view is called. You need to create the generator once, then refer to it in the view. For example:

```
# Outside the view
incrementing_letters = letter_counter

# Inside the view
addcodegenerate = codegenerate(initial={'id_gen': incrementing_letters})
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result..`<generator object lettercounter at 0x037B1030>`

Comment: @predator, I would fix my answer, but metatoaster's answer is better :).